# Shapes doesn't show on panel in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am drawing a rectangle using `CreateGraphics` with `MouseDrag` and on `MouseUp`, I add a `RectangleShape` (`Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks`). But the shape is not visible. Actually shape is added to `ShapeContainer`, but not shown. AND when I click on `Panel`, it shows up.

Below is my code to do so.

```
    Rectangle rect;
    Point p;
    Size s;
    bool mouseDown;
    private ShapeContainer shapeContainer1 = new ShapeContainer();

    public Form1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // This will reduce flicker (Recommended)
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.shapeContainer1.Parent = this.panel1;
        this.shapeContainer1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.SendToBack();
        s.Height = 0;
        s.Width = 0;
        p = this.panel1.PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);
        rect = new Rectangle(p, s);
        this.panel1.Invalidate();
        mouseDown = true;
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseDown)
        {
            this.panel1.SendToBack();
            p = this.panel1.PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);
            rect = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, p.X - rect.Left, p.Y - rect.Top);
            this.panel1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.panel1.CreateGraphics();

        if (mouseDown)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
            {
                this.panel1.SendToBack();
                g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
            }
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseUp (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.SendToBack();
        shapeContainer1.Size = this.panel1.Size;
        shapeContainer1.Location = this.panel1.Location;
        RectangleShape rectangle = new RectangleShape();
        rectangle.Location = rect.Location;
        rectangle.Size = rect.Size;
        rectangle.Name = "rectShape";
        rectangle.Parent = this.shapeContainer1;
        rectangle.Visible = true;
        this.shapeContainer1.Shapes.Add(rectangle);
    }
```

What is wrong with the code.? Following are some photos that shows the exact problem.

[image]

[image]

First photo shows that the rectangle is added to panel. When mouse moved, it disappears. Again when you click on the panel, is appears.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `Update()` after each of your calls to `Invalidate()`.

`Invalidate` indicates that the control should be repainted but you typically need the subsequent call to `Update` to force that painting to occur.

In your `OnPaint` override you should be calling `base.OnPaint(e)`.

Comment: Could not help. The same problem occurred. BTW edited the question for more description.

Comment: @DhavalR, it's hard to say exactly what is going wrong, but you are also missing the `base.OnPaint()` call in your `OnPaint` override.